# VBS on loop issue

Tags: loops, vbscript

I've got an issue on loop in vbs

My script is reading a file line per line and do some tasks.
I put on error resume next.

When an error occurs, script continues loop BUT with the next argument (the next line).
Is there a tips to make script continue loop with the same argument?

Here is the script.

```
on error resume next
dim filesys, text, readfile, contents, copy, oNet, objLog
set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set readfile = filesys.OpenTextFile("xxxx", 1, false)
set copy = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set oNet = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
set objLog = filesys.OpenTextFile("xxxx", 8, true)

do while readfile.AtEndOfStream=false
objLog.WriteLine "0"
contents = readfile.ReadLine
Drive = "Z:"
User = "xxx"
Pass = "xxx"
PER = "FALSE"
Share = "\\" & contents & "\c$\windows\temp"
oNet.MapNetworkDrive Drive, Share, PER, User, Pass
objLog.WriteLine "1"
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
objLog.WriteLine "1.1"
 objLog.WriteLine readfile.ReadLine & " ---- ATTENTION: " & Err.Description
'  wscript.echo "ATTENTION: " & Err.Description
 Err.Clear
End If
copy.CopyFile "Z:\xxx", "xxx" & contents & ".log"
objLog.WriteLine "2"
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
objLog.WriteLine "2.1"
 objLog.WriteLine readfile.ReadLine & " ---- ATTENTION: " & Err.Description
'  wscript.echo "ATTENTION: " & Err.Description
 Err.Clear
End If
objLog.WriteLine "3"
WScript.Sleep 5000
oNet.RemoveNetworkDrive "Z:"
objLog.WriteLine "4"
loop
readfile.close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of error, your

```
objLog.WriteLine readfile.ReadLine & " ---- ATTENTION: " & Err.Description
```

reads/uses up the next line from your source file. Use

```
objLog.WriteLine contents & " ---- ATTENTION: " & Err.Description
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry it seems to work.

I modified this on log :

```
objLog.WriteLine readfile.ReadLine & " ---- ATTENTION: " & Err.Description
```

by

```
objLog.WriteLine contents  & " ---- ATTENTION: " & Err.Description
```

Now the log is ok. It continues. Sorry for this :)